# Extract only number from a string

Tags: java

Supposedly I have a string that contains: `hello 14:12`.

Now I want to extract only the number and have two separate value in two variable like this: first_num value should be int i.e. first_num = 14 and the second variable should store the number after the colon (`:`) i.e. second_num = 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex to solve the problem

```
public static List<Integer> extractNumbers(String s){       
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        while(m.find()){
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
        }       
        return numbers;     
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

ReplaceAll is the best solution

```
String str = "hello 14:12";
str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" ")));
```

In this way you can attain only numbers in the array.